# Need statistics from US census

Tags: statistics, census

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, if so please recommend a stackexchange,

I am having a lot of issues getting the data approximations that I need for a report.

I am looking for the number of american households where the householder is aged between age 18-35 with annual income between 20,000 and 50,000. And also those with income more than 50,000.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about GIS at all.

Comment: [Open Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/) may be a better StackExchange. We'd be the correct one if you were relating that data to anything spatial ;)

Answer (score 1):

[American Fact Finder](http://factfinder.census.gov) contains searchable tables based on census data that should have all the information you are looking for.